# What is the best way to display user input as a custom font on a website?

Tags: php, input, fonts, imagemagick

I'm building a site for a custom vinyl shop, and I want to build a simple app that allows people to enter their desired text in an input box, choose a certain font, and then choose the pattern/color.

I've been looking into using Imagemagick or more specifically, Imagick for use with PHP. But I've seen some posts on here about using Gmagick and also ImageTTFtext. Just wondering what people feel is the best solution for my needs before I dive in.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to import fonts via CSS (and write a certain class for each font) and add that class to the input field instantly using ajax when people choose a that font.